# Inserting into Ordered HashTable with Position

Tags: powershell, hashtable, ordereddictionary

In PowerShell, I have a ordered hashtable that contains multiple keys and values. Based in the code, I am adding a value to the hashtable, but PowerShell appends the added key and value to the end of the list.

For example, my starting hashtable looks like:

```
$Hashtable = [ordered]@{
  A = 'a'
  B = 'b'
  C = 'c'
  X = 'x'
  Y = 'y'
  Z = 'z'
}
```

Now, let's say I want to insert a key that has `D = d` below `C = c`. If you run a `$Hashtable.add('D') = 'd'` then PowerShell will append it to the bottom of the list.

Is there a specific command for a hashtable that will let me specify exactly in the list where the **add** should be placed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell's ordered [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) are of .NET type [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary), so you can use the latter's **[`.Insert()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary.Insert)**, which allows you to specify the (`0`-based) target index for the insertion:

```sh
$Hashtable = [ordered]@{
  A = 'a'
  B = 'b'
  C = 'c'
  X = 'x'
  Y = 'y'
  Z = 'z'
}

$Hashtable.Insert(3, 'D', 'd')
```

Outputting `$Hashtable` afterwards yields the following, showing that the new `D` entry was inserted after the existing `C` entry (technically, inserted at the position previously occupied by the `X` entry):

```sh
Name                           Value
----                           -----
A                              a
B                              b
C                              c
D                              d     # <- inserted entry, index 3 (4th pos.)
X                              x
Y                              y
Z                              z
```